# What is the position of the dual of a plane in 3D space

Tags: transformation, computational-geometry, plane

I have a cube and a plane q that intersects the cube at one of its vertex v. Under dual transformation in geometry, the dual of a point in 3D is a plane and vice versa. The dual of a cube is an octahedron, where a vertex of the cube now becomes a face of the octehedron, and a face of the cube becomes a vertex of the octehedron.

Now what I want to know is where the dual of the plane q is. As q intersects the cube at vertex v, does it lie on the face (that corresponds to the dual of v) of the octahedron? Anyone can help me out on this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, sure. In the primal, the plane `q` is incident to the vertex `v`. Thus in the dual, `dual(v)` and `dual(q)` are also incident. That means that the `dual(q)` is a vertex that lies on the face `dual(v)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Irineau. Here, dual(v) is a supporting hyperplane of the octahedron, and their intersection is just a face f of the octahedron. dual(q) must lie on the hyperplane dual(v). But I am not quite sure whether dual(q) lies on the face f, or on the complementary part dual(v)-f, because both parts of dual(v) satisfy incidence relationship between dual(q) and dual(v). So, how to prove that dual(q) lies on the face f, but not on dual(v)-f? Is it possible to consider convex set properties for the proof? Thanks again!

Comment: That depends if your plane `q` intersects the cube somewhere else than at `v`.

Comment: So, you are saying that if q intersects the cube at v only, then dual(q) lies on the face f supporting by dual(v); if q goes through v and intersects the interior of the cube, then dual(q) lies on the complementary part dual(v)-f. Could you elaborate a bit on  possible ways to prove this? Thanks!